# Check for completeness and latest version - Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with product descriptions, parts number id, total number of parts and version of the product.

```
*product  part_id total_parts version*
Product1     1       3           0
Product1     2       3           0
Product2     1       1           0
Product2     1       1           1
Product3     1       2           0
Product3     2       2           0
```

I would like to add two columns. One to flag if all the parts are in the df (complete) and the other to flag if is the latest version of the product (is_the_latest).

The result should be like this:

```
   *product  part_id total_parts version* complete  is_the_latest
    Product1     1       3           0        N            Y
    Product1     2       3           0        N            Y
    Product2     1       1           0        Y            N    
    Product2     1       1           1        Y            Y
    Product3     1       2           0        Y            Y
    Product3     2       2           0        Y            Y
```

Versions can be in the range 0 to 4. Parts can be in the range 1 to 250. How can I create these flags?

Comment: What condition you are setting the flag to "Y" or "N" in both the new columns??

Comment: 'complete'  column should be Y for all the rows of the same product when all the parts are present. So, if the product has 4 parts, if we part 1,2,3 and 4. 'complete' = 'Y'.  is_the_latest columns should be 'Y' to all the rows whit the same project which the version is the latest. So, if we have 2 versions of Product2, those rows whit version 0 have to be filled with 'N' in the is_the_latest column. Only the rows of Product2 with version 1 should be filled with 'Y'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC try:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'product': {0: 'Product1', 1: 'Product1', 2: 'Product2',
                3: 'Product2', 4: 'Product3', 5: 'Product3'},
    'part_id': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 2},
    'total_parts': {0: 3, 1: 3, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 2, 5: 2},
    'version': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 1, 4: 0, 5: 0}
})

# Groupby product
g = df.groupby('product')

# Check if number of unique part ids matches expected number of parts
df['complete'] = np.where(
    g['part_id'].transform('nunique').eq(df['total_parts']),
    'Y',
    'N'
)

# Check that the max version equals the current version
df['is_the_latest'] = np.where(
    g['version'].transform('max').eq(df['version']),
    'Y',
    'N'
)

print(df)
```

`df`:

```
    product  part_id  total_parts  version complete is_the_latest
0  Product1        1            3        0        N             Y
1  Product1        2            3        0        N             Y
2  Product2        1            1        0        Y             N
3  Product2        1            1        1        Y             Y
4  Product3        1            2        0        Y             Y
5  Product3        2            2        0        Y             Y
```